# Why does VLC sometimes show green and defunct pixels over network?

Tags: wireless-networking, video, vlc-media-player

[VLC running wild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oYAl.png)

Sometimes, when playing MP4-files, stored on a NAS-drive, accessed over WLAN, VLC does crazy stuff like in the image above. This especially happens whenever the WLAN is busy and there's not much bandwidth left for playing the MP4-file. In such a situation, I can understand a "stuttering" video experience, but why those weird green boxes? There are other effects like that, like everything being behind "gray mud" until the next scene shows up*. Also, sometimes "blocks" move and "live on their own", moving left and right and changing colors. It's hard to describe, but I didn't have the opportunity to screenshot it.

Can anyone explain a., how these things happen? And b., how, if possible at all, to prevent them?

*Am I right that changing to a new scene in the video-file is important because some compression stuff keeping the barely-changing background as long as possible (i. e. until a new shot needs it)? I'm really unsure of how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much correct.  One of the ways MPEG video compression works is that it looks for changes in a frame.  Those blocks are the changes.  They could come from movement, changes in lighting, etc.  As you have stated, you see this when your network is bogged down.  You said you are using wireless, which of course has its variety of limitations.  The green boxes are there when VLC didnt get the data it needs in time to update the frame being shown.  I switched from wireless to [powerline networking](https://www.amazon.com/Powerline-Computer-Network-Adapters/b?ie=UTF8&node=1194444), as it has high bandwidth, low latency, can be put just about anywhere, etc.